# PHP Mailer - Receiving Spam Emails

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a website with a "book appointment" section which requires all fields to be completed before sending an email. Since the website is relatively popular, we get many requests during the day. I am using PHPMailer to receive e-mails.

Unfortunately, some of the email I receive are in this format:

```
A client has made a request to book an appointment. 

Client Name: 5c3a5beb89e89 

Client Email: sbethdddany5996@gmail.com 

Client Number:  

Message:
```

The e-mail is a spam email. How can I avoid this? The following is my PHP script.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "***";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tsl";
$mail->Port = ***;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '***';
$mail->Password = '***!';

$mail->setFrom($email, $totalName);
$mail->addAddress('***');
$mail->Subject = "Appointment Request";
$mail->Body = "A client has made a request to book an apointment.         
\n\nClient Name: $name \n\nClient Email: $email \n\nClient Number: $phone \n\nMessage: $msg";

if ($mail->send()){
  header('Location: index.html');
}
else{
  echo "Something went wrong, please try again.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Look into adding something like [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html) or alternatives for thwarting bots etc.

Comment: Great idea! Will look into it now. Are they done in php?

Comment: Google's reCAPTCHA service is just one of many implementations, and it would be integrated into your frontend with JavaScript. If your use-case is simple enough, you _could_ implement your own captcha with PHP but since this is a well-solved problem and a potential UX hassle, I'd recommend against that. I'd recommend you do some reading on the subject, look up some reviews and get an idea of the pros and cons.

Comment: Is your `requires all fields to be completed` client side? I don't see anything here requiring fields be completed.

Comment: Backend validation will save you a lot from such spam. Check for all fields before sending e-mail